# Completion Blocks Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I'm trying to write a completion handler in IOS with a block and am not sure exactly why it's not working.

This is what I have so far

```
typedef void(^myCompletion)(BOOL);

-(void) showAnswer {
   [self showAnswer:^(BOOL finished) {
       if (finished) {
         LnbScene *scene = (LnbScene *)gameScene.lnbScene;
         //once the tiles position have been updated then move to the next riddle
           [scene nextRiddle];
       }
   }];
}

// This method should update the position of tiles on the scene
    -(void) showAnswer:(myCompletion) compblock{
        LnbScene *scene = (LnbScene *)gameScene.lnbScene;
        NSArray *tilesArray = [scene.tilesBoundary children];

        for (Tile *tile in tilesArray) {
            if (tile.positionInAnswer != 17) {
                [tile removeFromParent];
                [scene.spacesBoundary addChild:tile];
                CGPoint targetPoint = CGPointMake(tile.targetPoint.x, tile.targetPoint.y + 6);
                tile.position = targetPoint;
            }
        }
        compblock(YES);
    }
```

And I am calling the showAnswer method from a Scene as follows:

```
     GameViewController *gVC = (GameViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
     [gVC showAnswer];
```

As I step through the code I don't encounter any errors and the sequence proceeds as expected ie.  The tile positions are changed and then the completion handler triggers to the nextRiddle method.  Only problem is that none of the interface is updated.  Is there something I am missing?

I've tested that the tile repositioned code works by taking out the completion block and I view it in the interface and get the desired results. So I'm pretty sure the problem lies in how I'm implementing the blocks.  I've never written a block before so I'm really in the dark.

```
-(void) showAnswer {
    LnbScene *scene = (LnbScene *)gameScene.lnbScene;
    NSArray *tilesArray = [scene.tilesBoundary children];

    for (Tile *tile in tilesArray) {
        if (tile.positionInAnswer != 17) {
            [tile removeFromParent];
            [scene.spacesBoundary addChild:tile];
            CGPoint targetPoint = CGPointMake(tile.targetPoint.x, tile.targetPoint.y + 6);
            tile.position = targetPoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You say that the "tile positions are changed", but that the interface isn't updated. Isn't the tile positions being changed what you want to see in the interface?

Comment: Sorry - I explained it poorly.  The tiles do not update on the interface.  I meant as I step through the code and examine it in the debugger that everything appears to work, but when I running and viewing the interface I do not see the desired results.  Neither does the next Riddle changes kick in in the interface.

Comment: My guess would be that your `scene` object is nil when you are calling the `showAnswer` method. Your block code is fine. The other possibility is that you're trying to update the UI outside of the main thread but it doesn't look like it at least from the code you've posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem seems to be a conceptual mistake - that the "flow" of code 
in the `-(void) showAnswer:(myCompletion) comp block` method truthfully represents **the flow of UI elements in time** in the presentation layer.

However in practice it is not that straightforward. The UI layer is rendered with 60 Hz framerate. That means you see 60 (frames) screens per second and contents of each of those screens needs to be calculated in advance, processed, flattened, rendered.

That means 1 frame (screen) cycle/pass lasts approx. 16 milliseconds. If I remember correctly you as a programmer have 11 milliseconds to provide all the relevant code so that it can be processed into visual info. This chunk of code is processed **all at once** which is the **answer to our problem**.

Imagine if you had a method that would say

```
{
   //some other UI code...
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; 
   //some other UI code...
}
```

Now imagine we are inside 1 such 16 millisecond pass.
This piece of code would be processed in advance before any rendering happens and the resultative background colour will be yellow. Why? Because in the cycle preparation phase this code is processed and the framework interprets the green colour as pointless because the value is immediately overwritten by a yellow one.
Thus instructions for the renderer will contain only the yellow background information.

Now back to your actual code. I think all your code is processed fast enough to fit into that 11 milisec window, and the problem is that you do not really wait for the swapping of tiles because there is that block with YES parameter as part of the method and that one already slides to whatever is next.

So the rendered does get instructions to simply move on the the next thing. And it does not animate.

Try putting this "tile swapping" into the "animation" block
[UIview animateWithDuration:....completion] method..and put your block into the completion block. Yes you will have a block in a block but thats fine.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                 animations:^{
                                 //tile swapping code
                            }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                             {
                                 complBlock(YES);
                             }];
```

I am not completely sure if it will work but let's try.

Comment: Still digesting all of the above.  Will get back to you and see if it works.

Comment: this WWDC video talks about it in much more detail.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#419

Comment: I've found the problem with my code - it was with the [scene nextRiddle] method.  the next Riddle method instantiated a new GameViewController.  But I like your solution above of using the UIView animateWithDuration.  I think it will look a lot smarter. So thanks for your help.  and I'll take a look at that video

Answer (score 0):

The UI relate method should call on main thread. U can try this:

```
[self showAnswer:^(BOOL finished) {
   if (finished) {
     LnbScene *scene = (LnbScene *)gameScene.lnbScene;

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          [scene nextRiddle];
     });
   }
}];
```